# In Javascript onkeypress Event,Tab button does not fire(In Mozilla Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a textbox, I need to validate my textbox using `onkeypress` (to restrict special characters). It works fine in Chrome. In Mozilla Firefox it does not fire (Tab Button). Is there any events to add in my code?

My code:

```
function alpha(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 9);   //k=9(keycode for tab)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not 9? It is on my Windows 7 computer.

Comment: Like putvande said, keycode for tab is 9 http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Could you post the code were your associating the event to the event handler ?

Comment: Now i tried 9... but it does not works @Anton

Comment: What browser + system are you using @Vicky?

Answer (score 1):

test this code

```
function alpha(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 9) { //Tab keycode
      //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
function alpha(e){
    var k = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 9);   //k=9(keycode for tab)
}
```